# Paypal sent warning emails for IPN

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

I have integrated Paypal in my Django(1.10) app using Django-paypal package. Everything works fine even payments processing perfectly well and I'm receiving IPNs from PayPal in Django admin. But PayPal send this email to me as:

> Hello XXXXXXXXXX,
>
> Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:
>
> https://XXXXXXXXXX/paypal/ipn/
>
> If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
>   that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
>   with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be
>   disabled for your account.
>
> Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.
>
> Thanks, PayPal
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------- PROTECT YOUR PASSWORD
>
> NEVER give your password to anyone, including PayPal employees.
>   Protect yourself against fraudulent websites by opening a new web
>   browser (e.g. Internet Explorer or Firefox) and typing in the PayPal
>   URL every time you log in to your account.
>
> Please do not reply to this email. We are unable to respond to
>   inquiries sent to this address. For immediate answers to your
>   questions, visit our Help Centre by clicking "Help" located on any
>   PayPal page or email.
>
> PayPal is committed to your privacy, learn more about our privacy
>   policy: https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full

What issue can be occurred?
I don't have any idea about that, help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like PayPal is observing the IPN fails in your PayPal account, hence PayPal is sending a warning email for notifying you about the IPN fails. If there is a continuous IPN fail then PayPal will disable the IPN in your PayPal account. You can view the last 28 days IPN data in your PayPal account for knowing the failed IPN's. If there are no failed IPN's in your PayPal account for last 28 days but still receiving this email from PayPal then please get in touch with PayPal support team at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com for further help.